# Need more insights about this css selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<head>   
    <style>
        .thisOne{ background: red;}
        div[class*="thisTwo"] { background: green}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="thisOne">
        <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thisTwo">
        <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
    </div> 
</body>
```

I'm wondering which is the different between this way to select:

1. `.thisOne{ background: red;}`
2. `div[class*="thisTwo"] { background: green}`

They do pretty much the same job, right? why is 2-selector more advance then?

Comment: What do you mean by "more advance"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, they don't do the same thing. The attribute selector that functions identically to `div.thisTwo` is `div[class~="thisTwo"]`. Notice the use of `~` rather than `*`. Not to mention your `.thisOne` selector also lacks the `div` in front.

`div[class*="thisTwo"]` selects any `div` whose `class` attribute contains the string `thisTwo`, but *it doesn't account for any spaces separating this string* from other classes. It just looks for the string anywhere in the attribute value.

This means that it would match the following element, which `div.thisTwo` could not possibly match because it has only *one class* `thisOne-thisTwo`, which contains the string `thisTwo`, and not *two separate classes* `thisOne` and `thisTwo`:

```
<div class="thisOne-thisTwo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No the don't. The first will select any element with class name `thisOne`. The second will select any `div` that its class contains the term `thisTwo`.